# Navigation based application template in ipad sdk

Tags: ipad

is Navigation based application template in ipad sdk is include at release time

Answer (score 0):

No.

Apple suggests to use Split View based application on iPad instead of Navigation based application.
Read iPad HIG "Flatten Your Information Hierarchy" chapter for more information.

Comment: Will Apple ban ipad apps that contradict their suggestion? Sometimes a nav-view is the way to go...